# Is it correct to say that $\int e^{-x^2}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series

Is it correct to say that:

$$\int e^{-x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$

I know that the stuff inside the summation is used as a formula for finding the n-th term in the series that equals $e^{-x^2}$ (the first bit of the series I speak of is: $C+x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^4}{10}-...)$.

Since that's the case, wouldn't it be correct to say that the integral of $e^{-x^2}$ is indeed equal to that summation? Just wanting to be sure because I've never seen this explicitly stated anywhere.

Edit: to clarify, what I've done here is apply term-by-term integration to the power series representation of $e^{-x^2}$, which you can easily find by replacing $x$ with $-x^2$ in the power series for $e^x$.

Comment: You are allowed to integrate the power series to get an antiderivative (just make sure to start at $n=0$). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2159110/antiderivative-of-ex2-correct-or-fallacy) is a similar question.

Comment: Your question could use some more clarification.

Comment: Are you sure about the summation starting at $n=1$?

Comment: @mrtaurho That was a typo, thanks!

Comment: @NoChance could you clarify what I need to clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to a constant factor this is precisely the series representation of the so-called [Error Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series) which is *defined as*

> $$\operatorname{erf}(z):=\frac2{\sqrt \pi}\int_0^z e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx$$

Expanding the exponential within and integrating termwise afterwards $($make sure that this can be justified here!$)$ yields to the the result you gave. Note that for the indefinite integral we have to add a constant of integration.

Thus, it is indeed correct to state that

$$\int e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx~=~\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}+C$$

But more common, since the Error Function itself is widely used, to say that

$$\int_0^z e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx~=~\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}$$

Matching the aforementioned definition of the Error Function omitting the constant factor for a moment.

Comment: I'd heard of the error function but hadn't looked into it deeply; I had no idea this was it! It's also insightful to see the definite integral from $0$, nice to know that the error function is actually pretty simple. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JamesRonald No problem, glad to help! Feel free to accept the answer to show that you are satisfied; if not, tell me what I possible could improve further.

Comment: apologies, I had no idea that feature existed haha. Done now, thanks again